# How to bind array to IN condition with Node postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm struggling to figure out of to bind an array to an IN query in node [`pg` library](https://node-postgres.com/).

```js
  const env = 'foo';
  const sourceTypes = ['one', 'two'];

  const resp = await pool.query(
    `SELECT source_id, target_id FROM records
    WHERE target_env = $1
    AND source_type IN ($2)`,
    [env, sourceTypes],
  );
```

I've tried several variations and they either error out or don't return any data.

I can make the query when I just use when I manually bind to generate something like this:

```sql
SELECT source_id, target_id FROM records
    WHERE target_env = 'foo'
    AND source_type IN ('one', 'two')
```

PS: If can provide suggestion on how to actually see the SQL request that PG is generating, that would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't bind an array to multiple elements of a list in one go.  But you can use an array instead of a list by changing `in ($2)` to `=ANY($2)`

You can see what queries are getting sent by setting `log_statement=all` and then viewing the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: Pretty much the exact same example here, but using `=ANY($1)` is giving `error: malformed array literal: "ABC123"` with params simply `['ABC123']`.  Was there anything else subtle I've missed?

Comment: oh wait, it's me ... should be double brackets: an array of parameters to the query, and the `ANY` parameter itself which is an array, so in my example `[['ABC123']]`.  Works a treat now - thanks @jjanes